# What is this kind of internship called?

Tags: management, internship, job-description

During the last summer I was at an internship within a organisation where I had to work with multiple departments. I was tasked to work with one department every two weeks. So on the first two weeks I was tasked to work in the sales department, the next two weeks I worked in the purchase department and  henceforth. I have been asked to compile a report on my internship but I can not bring myself to describe what kind of internship it was. Can you help out?

Comment: multi disciplinary internship sounds good

Answer (score 2):

> What is this kind of internship called?

Where I worked this would be called an internship doing a rotation.

Answer (score -1):

I'd call i "a rotating internship."

Also this question might belong in the "English language" questions. Based on " i can not bring myself to describe what kind of internship it was," which would mean you fear or dread describing it rather than "I can't think/decide (or figure out- more colloquial) how to describe it," which says you don't know what it would be called.